# Prevent promotion on specific node in Pacemaker

Tags: pacemaker, drbd

I have a drbd + pacemaker cluster with three nodes, one being a quorum device only. I'm trying to configure the pacemaker resource so that the promotable drbd-resource should run on all three devices, but it should never be promoted on the quorum device. I've tried setting location constraints on the resource, but that results in pacemaker not starting the resource at all on the quorum device so drbd can't keep quorum on a failover.

The desired state would be:

- drbd resource is started on all three nodes
- drbd resource is promotable
- pacemaker will never promote the quorum device

I can't find anything in the documentation, but what I'm envisioning would be a parameter like "don't promote on device X" that I have missed for the drbd resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple location constraint isn't enough for this task. Pacemaker `rules` can handle more advanced expressions needed for this.

Depending on the RHEL/Pacemaker version one of these rules should work for you:

```
# pcs constraint location <clone> rule role=promoted score=-INFINITY node eq <quorum-node-name>

# pcs constraint location <clone> rule role=master score=-INFINITY node eq <quorum-node-name>
```